# Proof step motivation in proving that set of rationals whose square is less than 2 has no upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am flaring up my old mathematical hobby and picked up Rudin for reading. My motivation is to read with complete understanding, and thus I am trying to motivate all steps of all propositions laid out.

On page 2 it is stated (not-cited) :

> Set of rationals whose square is less than 2 does not contain a greatest element

The first idea of the proof which came to my mind is to use the fact that between any two rationals, there is another rational. I proceeded by writing down $A = \{q \in \mathbb{Q} \vert q^2 < 2\}$ and $l \in A$. Now I wanted to consider the gap between number $l$ and $2$, and then any smaller gap should lead me to a rational which is less than $2$ as in:

$$l^2 < 2 \implies 0 < 2 - l^2 $$

Thus for any integer $m \geq 2$ it will hold that $l^2 + \frac{2-l^2}{m}$ is going to be a rational. The problem is that I can not construct proper $m$, so that :

$$(l+\frac{2-l^2}{m})^2 < 2$$

My problem with understanding is that in the book $m$ is simply said to be $l+2$, which does work, but I do not understand how to arrive at such conclusion that proper choice for $m$ is $l+2$

I would be grateful for your assistance.

EDIT: Rudin as in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin

Comment: i agree with you that verifying that $~m = (l+2) \in \Bbb{Q}~$ *works* is distinct from **deriving** the value of $~m = (l+2).~$  Somewhat off topic, I personally dislike Rudin's entire approach here.  Much simpler is that $~A~$ is a non-empty subset of $~\Bbb{R}~$ that is bounded above, and so has a least upper bound in $~\Bbb{R}. ~$  It is then straightforward to show that in $~\Bbb{R},~$  the least upper bound of $~A~$ is equal to $~\sqrt{2}.~$  So, the entire problem reduces to showing that $~\sqrt{2}~$ is not rational.  This is easily confirmed by googling "sqrt 2 not rational proof".

Comment: Re my last comment, showing that in $~\Bbb{R},~$ the least upper bound of $~A~$ is $~\sqrt{2},~$ requires the preliminary result that the rational numbers are *dense* in $~\Bbb{R}.~$ That is, between any two real numbers $~r_1, r_2 ~: r_1 < r_2,~$ there exists $~q \in \Bbb{Q}~$ such that $~r_1 < q < r_2.$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have right now settled for "mere proof" that for any $l \in A$ I can pick a natural number $n$, such that $(l  + \frac{1}{n})^2 < 2$, since I can always fit a rational into the gap between $l^2$ and $2$

Comment: Yes, your latest approach, which also requires the preliminary result that the rational numbers are dense in $~\Bbb{R},~$ also works.